# How to parse XML Schema File

Tags: c#, xml, xsd

Good day.

How to parse XML Schema(.xsd) file and generate to c# class file.

About my project:

Step1.
Parse XSD file (C# lang)  ----Build Time -----> Generate CCode Dictionary(C# Class)

Step2.
Paser XML file(C# lang)   ----Run Time -----> Fill the CCode Dictionary with the XML file value (C# App)

I researched the tools of XSD.exe / XSDObjectGen Tool etc. I found the C# class can't be used for my project.

That's why i want to parse the XSD file by myself.
I searched MSDN and found the the information:
Namespace:  System.Xml.Schema
But i don't know which class if better for me for using.

Any help will be appreciated.

BR!
Nano

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my project I successfully used xsd.exe to do this, with this command line:

xsd.exe schema.xsd /classes

What in the classes generated make them inappropriate for use in your project?

Answer (score 2):

Or you can use the [Xsd2Code](http://xsd2code.codeplex.com) command-line and Visual Studio add-in utility.

With Xsd2Code, you can right-click on a XSD file in your Visual Studio Solution Explorer and have it create the C# file for you:

[alt text http://i3.codeplex.com/Project/Download/FileDownload.aspx?ProjectName=Xsd2Code&DownloadId=41336](http://i3.codeplex.com/Project/Download/FileDownload.aspx?ProjectName=Xsd2Code&DownloadId=41336)

Comment: Hello marc_s,

i found "Xsd2Code is an AddIn for visual studio 2008" from http://xsd2code.codeplex.com/.

Does it work well for VS2005?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Nano: I don't know - I am no longer using VS2005. What does the documentation say? If you're not sure - ask on the xsd2code discussion board at Codeplex.